# excel type mismatch error on a private sub

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have this sub that should update the value of a cell when a corresponding cell is changed, but i keep getting an error that says error 13 type mismatch, ive looked up all the possible sources of this problem and cant figure out what is causing it, here is my code that is presenting the problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
'Adds unique keyA values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column H
    If Not Intersect(Target, range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Cells.Value <> "" And Target.Row > 7 And Target.Row <= 20 Then

'Update the "KeyA" value
            range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now()

        End If

    End If
'Adds unique keyB values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column J
    If Not Intersect(Target, range("J:J")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Cells.Value <> "" And (Target.Row > "7" And Target.Row <= "27") Then

'Update the "KeyB" value
            range("M" & Target.Row).Value = Now()

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

the error occurs when i try to clear the range its checking for change. any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What? When you delete something in column H or J on the sheet you get the error?

Comment: exactly, ive even gone so far as in the code that deletes it, to name each individual cell and set its value = ""

Comment: What about `If Not IsEmpty(Target)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting that `Target` is a range and does not necessarily consist of one cell only. If you adjust your code a bit it should work:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Range

'Adds unique keyA values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column H
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString And Target.Row > 7 And Target.Row <= 20 Then
            'Update the "KeyA" value
            Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
        End If
    Next cell
End If

'Adds unique keyB values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column J
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J:J")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString And (Target.Row > "7" And Target.Row <= "27") Then
            'Update the "KeyB" value
            Range("M" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
        End If
    Next cell
End If

End Sub
```

Basically, the change is that it checks now **each** cell in the range `Target` and works your code for each cell in that range. Before, you were comparing (possibly) multiple `Target.Values` to `""`. That didn't work. Now, only one `.Value` gets compared to `""` and that should solve it.

Comment: what does option explicit do in that first line of code?

Comment: Whenever you don't understand a keyword, simply highlight (select) it and then press `F1`. This will guide you to the following website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855.aspx Basically, it says that all variables in your code must be declared (using `Dim`) before they can be used. That's only for good coding practice and the above code will work without that line. I just include it in all of my modules. You can remove it if you want to.